# corrupted magit

Tags: magit, osx

Last week I had to abort a rebase in magit. Soon after my computer became  unstable so I rebooted.

Today, when I do `C-x g` for `magit-status`, I get an error in the status line

```
Setting current directory: No such file or directory, /Users/user1/project/subproject/.git/rebase-merge/
```

Instead of the magit-status display, I get an empty window.
The mode line indicates

```
0   1: 0 UU-R-*magit: subproject                             All Magit company EditorConfig +
```

So far, I tried

```
$ brew services stop emacs
Stopping `emacs`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `emacs` (label: homebrew.mxcl.emacs)
$ brew services start emacs
==> Successfully started `emacs` (label: homebrew.mxcl.emacs)
$ alias emacs
alias emacs='emacsclient -nw'
$
```

Comment: Can you fix it via the git command line tools?

Comment: git command line shows no issues.  git status shows all clear.

Comment: Try `git rebase --abort`.

Comment: tried it. git command line says theres no rebase in progress.

Comment: And HEAD is *not* detached? If so delete `.git/rebase-merge`, `.git/rebase-apply`. Otherwise also try a `git cherry-pick --abort`.

Comment: head is not detached

Comment: try `git fsck` and see if there are any problems with Git's database. Perhaps, try cloning this repository into a different location from a remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brew uninstall emacs and then reinstalling fixed it

Answer (score 5):

I had the same symptoms after doing a rebase. I'm not sure exactly what happened; I started an interactive rebase in magit and, I think, switched away from the revision rearrangement screen (the `git-rebase-todo` buffer) and forgot that I had a rebase going on and did other things.

The problem turned out that there was an open buffer visiting

```
.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo
```

After closing this buffer, magit no longer tried to access the non-existent `rebase-merge` directory.